# Jquery UI sortable with bootstrap columns - right hand edge drop pushes lower rows down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-sortable

I have created a test script for using JQuery UI 1.12.1, JQuery 3.1.0 and Bootstrap 3.3.7.

I is all nearly working apart from one problem.  I have created the fiddle below

https://jsfiddle.net/woldsnewmedia/aLm44L8p/

The problem is that when a Div is dragged over a Div at the right hand edge, everything jumps down.  Anyone spot where I am going wrong?  The code is here:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><!-- v3.3.7 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script><!-- v3.1.0 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- v3.3.7 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery-ui.js"></script><!-- v1.12.1 -->

  <style type="text/css">

    .dragdrop-placeholder {
        background-color:red;
        margin-top:18px!important;
        margin-left:15px!important;
    }

    .hnd1{
        height:200px;
        background-color:blue;
    }

  </style>

  <title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.wrow1').sortable({

        connectWith: ".wdragdrop1",
        handle: ".wdragdrop1",
        placeholder: "dragdrop-placeholder",

        update: function (e, ui) { 
                var widget_ids = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                console.log(widget_ids);
              },

        start: function(e, ui){
         ui.placeholder.width(ui.item.find('.wdragdrop1').width());
         ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.find('.wdragdrop1').height());
         ui.placeholder.addClass(ui.item.attr("class"));
        }

    });


});

</script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row wrow1">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="1">

            <div class="wdragdrop1">
                <h3 class="hnd1">Box 1</h3>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="2">

            <div class="wdragdrop1">
                <h3 class="hnd1">Box 2</h3>
            </div>

            </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="3">

            <div class="wdragdrop1">
                <h3 class="hnd1">Box 3</h3>
            </div>

            </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="4">

            <div class="wdragdrop1">
                <h3 class="hnd1">Box 4</h3>
            </div>

            </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="5">

            <div class="wdragdrop1">
                <h3 class="hnd1">Box 5</h3>
            </div>

            </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="6">

            <div class="wdragdrop1">
                <h3 class="hnd1">Box 6</h3>
            </div>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All col-**-# should sum up to 12 per row. If it's more then the next element will go to the next row.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  But if you look at the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/woldsnewmedia/aLm44L8p/ you will see that the layout only messes up during a drag.  The layout appears fine otherwise.  Try dragging once loaded "Box 1" over "Box 4" and you will see what I mean.